# Method of Hydraulic Resistances (Crane TP 410), how accurate is it really?

Tags: fluid-mechanics, fluid, systems-design

A bit vague but a question for you working engineers out there.

For a couple of years now I've been designing fluid systems, mostly using Crane's TP 410 as the guiding resource for pressure drop calculation and flow rate calculations. One thing that has bothered me is that I've never really gotten to validate my models against real life systems.

My question is, **in the field how well does this method hold up ? Are the modeled results fairly accurate?** Anecdotal evidence is welcome as well as something more concrete like a trade study.

I understand this isn't a traditional question you'd get on this site, so if this is the wrong forum just let me know and I'll take down my question.

Comment: Measure the power necessary on one of your designed systems - or have they not made it of the design board?

Comment: I'm a little unclear of what you mean @SolarMike. Correct me if I'm wrong but when you say design board do you mean prototyping board/ bread board? If so, the systems and method I am asking about is related to fluid systems (ie. piping systems) and not electrical systems.

Comment: I did **not** assume electrical systems or breadboards, I made the comment that if one of your hydraulic pipe / system designs has made it into production ie they took what you designed and built it, then you would be able to measure the energy input required to make it work and the output and calculate the efficiency from there. Of course , if none of your designs are actually produced then that might be somewhat challenging...

Comment: Roger, thanks for the clarification. The reason I haven't been able to test as you described is because some system's are still waiting to be constructed and others are operated by end users outside our organization. So I don't really have access to that "real world" feed back unfortunately